# Property 'loadIntoLocation' does not exist on type 'DynamicComponentLoader'

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get loadIntoLocation working, but I keep get the error message,

**Property 'loadIntoLocation' does not exist on type 'DynamicComponentLoader'.**

I've looked at other examples and used plunker and it works there, but I can't seem to get it working locally. I grep'd the Angular2 core and could not find any mention of a loadIntoLocation function.

How do I find out what version of angular2 I'm using? Can I upgrade? I just used npm install to deploy my environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was removed a while ago as far as I remember. `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated anyway. Use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` instead.

For a full example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: Thank you so much. A lot of information out there is outdated, so it's hard to keep track of what to use. I spent so much time trying to figure this out; should have posted this question sooner.